# JTable not displaying in the initialization

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm having a rare problem with this.
When I put the code in a button´s event it works and the table is properly displayed, but when I place it below the `initComponents()` function (inside the constructor) it does not work.

```java
String[] columnNames = {"Nick", "E-Mail"};
Object[][] data = {
{"Kathy", "abc@hotmail.com"},
{"John", "Doe"},
{"Sue", "Black"},
{"Jane", "White"},
{"Joe", "Brown"}

};

   jPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
   JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
   Dimension dim = new Dimension(jPanel1.getWidth(),jPanel1.getHeight());
   JScrollPane tableScroll = new JScrollPane(table);
   tableScroll.setPreferredSize(dim);
   jPanel1.add(tableScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   jPanel1.validate();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I changed the jPanel1.getWidth() for a number and it worked! Its like that function is returning 0 at the beggining. I dont know why

Comment: You shouldn't set the JScrollPane's preferredSize but rather let your layout managers do that for you.

Comment: If i dont set the preferredSize it fills the entire screen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- replace `Dimension dim = new Dimension(jPanel1.getWidth(),jPanel1.getHeight());`
- because before `JFrame.pack()` or `JFrame.setVisible(true)` returns zero dimension [0, 0]

  ---
- with `table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());`

Comment: When i do that the scroll does not work and i cant see the entire table.

Comment: I fixed it with
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(jPanel1.getPreferredSize());

Thanks!